# Unable to install MS SQL Server or SSMS due to missing DLL, how do I find and install this DLL?

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server, sql, ssms

I have the exact issue as the OP of this question but their fix did not work for me:

[Related Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561319/sql-server-management-studio-fatal-error-during-installation-0x80070643#comment118630686_65561319)

I need to install MS SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio on my computer. No matter what I try to install (SQL Server, SSMS, SQL Server 2012 Native Client) I get an error saying that it is missing a DLL.

This seems to be the relevant part of the log file. The percent complete starts counting down after all this as it removes everything it just installed.

```
[3C14:0104][2021-04-16T14:40:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[3C14:0104][2021-04-16T14:40:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i319: Applied execute package: sqlncli.msi, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 
[3C14:0104][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i318: Skipped rollback of package: sqlncli.msi, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 
[1520:0A84][2021-04-16T14:40:07]i319: Applied rollback package: sqlncli.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
```

From searching around online, [I have found the missing DLL is sqlncli11.dll](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdd43c6a-f0ce-422f-9f2a-94baa727cddc/i-cant-install-the-computer-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqlgetstarted) which should be in the C:\Windows\System32 folder (maybe SysWOW64 for 64 bit?). The problem is that I have no idea how to replace this missing DLL. I have not been able to find where to download it on the Microsoft website and I'm not about to download it from some other sketchy site. I thought it would come as part of the SQL Server 2012 Native Client but that had the same error while trying to install.

I have tried every other fix I have been able to find except reinstalling Windows and editing my registry, which both seem like nuclear options.

Comment: The OP in the question you linked to did find a solution: it's in the comment before your one.

Comment: I should've been more explicit, but I attempted that to no avail. That was part of "every other fix except reinstalling windows".

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402

Comment: Do you have the option of trying SQL Server 2019? Otherwise, and I know it isn't in the spirit of Super User, there should be a MS support website for SQL Server Installation, and if someone from MS gets on it they will guide you through all the fiddly bits to make it work.

Comment: Oh, hang on, did you run the SQL Server installation as Admininistrator? That can get round a lot of strange problems.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have downloaded and attempt to install that. Same issue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried SQL Server 2019 Express as administrator and that did not help. I might try the MS support website but in my experience Stack Exchange has been more helpful and there are already many threads about this issue with a lot of dead ends or "reinstall windows" type answers on MS support

Comment: ***maybe SysWOW64 for 64 bit?*** as stupid as is sounds.. SysWOW64 holds your 32 bit files.  When you run 32 bit programs, windows fakes this folder to be system32

Comment: Steal the file from another working windows machine that does not have this issue.. you might find that this is the first of many problems that you might have.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for the input. That is weird about SysWOW64, I just saw that someone found the file there so I wasn't sure what the difference was. I will start looking for the file on other computers. I have searched two so far with no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.